# Using Java variables with Sikuli in Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

The code below is a Java code in Selenium Webdriver. The code reads a long list from an excel sheet. It stores the values in each excel cell in variables, `LastName` and  `FirstName`. I need to use the variables in a query, after navigating to SQL Server management studio database. This is where am having issues. when I use the command  'screen.type(LastName);', the variable `LastName` throws "cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

How do I use the variables `LastName` and `FirstName` defined in Java in Sikuli.

```
File src = new File ("C:\\EmployeeList.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
System.out.println("Total Row is :" + rowcount);

for (int i=0; i<rowcount;i++) {
    String LastName=sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();   
    String FirstName=sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();  
    System.out.println("Data Employee List is " +i+ " "+"is "+ LastName+ ", "+FirstName+");
}

wb.close();

//Navigated into SQL Server management studio database
  screen.type(LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`LastName` is declared in the `for` loop local scope, so it doesn't exist outside the `for`. You need to declare it outside

```
String lastName, firstName;
for (int i = 0 ; i < rowcount ; i++) {
    lastName = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();   
    firstName = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();  
    System.out.println("Data Employee List is " + i + " " + "is " + lastName + ", " + firstName);
}

screen.type(lastName);
```

I'm not sure if this on purpose, but `screen.type(lastName);` will use only the **last** value of `lastName`. If you want to use all of them insert it into the loop. In that case you can leave the `lastName` declaration inside the `for`

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < rowcount ; i++) {
    String lastName = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();   
    String firstName = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println("Data Employee List is " + i + " " + "is " + lastName + ", " + firstName);
    screen.type(lastName);
}
```

By the way, variables in Java should start with lower case.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help. The purpose is to get the values from each cell of a row in the excel sheet. Use the values in a SQL query, then go back for the next row in the excel sheet.